# Jupyter notebook to run await function

Tags: python

Upon learning [Coroutines and Tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) on Jupyter notebook ,

Run the following codes

```
import asyncio
async def main():
    print('learn')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('Jupyter')
```

[image]

However, it works properly on Ipython

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3397) with later versions of Jupyter.  Install [`nest_asyncio`](https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio) as a [workaround](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3397#issuecomment-419386811).

```
> pip install nest_asyncio
```

**Code**

```
import asyncio

import nest_asyncio


nest_asyncio.apply()


async def main():
    print("Learn")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("Jupyter")


asyncio.run(main())
# 'Learn'
# 'Jupyter'
```

*TLDR*; Running asyncio in notebooks conflicts with the existing event loop run by Tornado 5.0 in the background.  A second option is to downgrade `notebook` to a version that depends on an older version of Tornado.